# file opened before function call (optimization issue)?

Tags: c, file, optimization, stat

I am trying to understand this better... I have a function in main that is called only when certain conditions are true - inside that function is...

```
struct stat attr_buff;
if (stat( filename, &attr_buff ) == -1) {

  ... " exit etc " ...
}
```

If all that is satisfied, then another thread is created which processes the file - and opens it with:

```
f = fopen ((char *) filename, "rb");

if (f == NULL) {

  ... " exit etc " ...
}
```

But! If I turn on optimization -O3 in gcc, even if the function in main is not called, I get a segfault because it starts opening the file even before all the checks are done? I must admit I am a bit puzzled. Let me just mention that, if I use access() instead of stat(), everything is fine. But, I want stat() due to portability... What is going on?

Comment: This looks like a race condition. And please show more code instead of describing it.

Comment: BTW  `access` is no less portable as `stat` AFAIK, but there is definitely a problem somewhewre within your code. If you use `access`, it may work today, but it may fail tomorrow or after an update of your OS or it may fail on another computer etc.

Comment: Please post an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's unclear atm what exactly you're talking about.

Comment: What kind of checks are being done? Is it possible that one of these checks is opening in a separate thread (or needs a value from another thread) - thus you would need to wait for it to open the file? Or are they just value comparrison in a single-threaded procedure?

Comment: Also, checking if a file exists before opening it is a [TOCTOU  bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  The file can be deleted after you check.  The file can have its permissions changed after you check.  The file can have other restrictions on it (ACLs, SELinux) that prevent you from opening it even though the permissions from `stat()` say you can open it. In other words, the "check" part of "check the file, then open it" is useless. It's **not** opening the file, so it's not definitively telling you opening the file will work, and it can still change post-check.

Comment: Sorry, I will try to add more code, ASAP. As far as I know if a file could not be opened, it should return null pointer... And this check works fine without optimization. I tried also making file handle volatile, but to no avail... So I thought doing another stat() and access() before fopen() would somehow prevent rest of code from running...

Comment: You are already checking for a nullpointer after `fopen`. So where does the segfault happen?

Comment: It happens right when the program starts, long before all the checks. It seems to me that optimization somehow reasons that file will be opened in any case and starts opening it right at the beginning of program.

Comment: @Krpan you need to find out where exactly the segfault happens. There is certainly a bug in the code you don't show in the question.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I fixed it, basically it was a nasty overlook. I was iterating through args[] over i, but doing all checks only on args[1]. :-)